# symfony 2 and phpunit crawler client does not reach ngnix

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have written this simple test:

```
<?php
namespace Hello\ApiBundle\Tests\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;

class HelloControllerTest extends WebTestCase {
    public function test() {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $crawler = $client->request("GET","http://localhost/hello");
        $response = $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode();
        var_dump($response);
    }
}
?>
```

When I am running this test, it prints a 404 status code.

Oddly, I don't see the request on ngninx access log. Even if I change the URL to `"/hello"` it still looks like the request isn't reaching the local webserver.

Needless to say it works if I just open Chrome and try this URL (`http://localhost/hello`) normally.

- What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because Symfony's test framework actually only simulates request (and run dispatcher directly behind). It doesn't send a real request.

When you are testing your app, use relative paths:

```
$crawler = $client->request("GET","/hello");
```